# Cómo poner el botón atrás de forma visual en navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un Tab Bar controller, esta es uno de las opciones, quiero un botón atras en el navigation controller, porque el tab bar quiero que quede oculto al entrar en cada opción (esto ya me informaron como hacerlo)

al arrastrar el tab bar button del navigation controller al codido tampoco me crea el UIAction, que seria lo lógico, así se crearía el botón  atras de forma automatica

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar un `Bar Button Item` al lado izquierdo del `Navigation Item` de tu `View Controller`.

En el `action` de ese botón agregas el siguiente código:

```
@IBAction func backButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Cuando tienes un `Table View Controller` y agregas el `segue` a un `View Controller` te aparece automáticamente el botón para regresar.

Comment: Cuando uso TVC solos con botones por ejemplo se que me aparece el botón atras. Ahora al mezclar TVC con TBC es el lio. Agrego el botón tal como dices y se dibuja bien, pero no retrocede, el action lo pongo bien